# CSS media queries aren't working in the same stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm familiar with responsive design + CSS.

But for some odd reason the only media query that isn't working is the mobile dimension style.

I'm using chrome to monitor what style is being applied and it only loads the min-device-width styles only.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I also have the below in my index file.
**UPDATED**

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

@media (max-device-width: 480px){
/* Styles */
#profilebody_avatar
{
width: 10em;
}
.profilebody_name{
font-size: 90%;
font-weight: 500;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 0 0 2pt #000;
}
}
@media (min-device-width: 1024px){
#profilebody_avatar
{
width: 20em;
}
.profilebody_name{
font-size: 90%;
font-weight: 500;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 0 0 2pt #000;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you actually checking this on a mobile? Or are you simply resizing your browser window? Because it says `max-device-width` not `max-width`, which means, as long as your monitor is wider than `480px`, you're not going to see anything different. Either check on a small screen or update it to `max-width` for Responsive Design rather than Adaptive.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> check that you have the appropriate meta to your html markup

Comment: I'm just resizing the browser window.. I thought browsers we're able to respond to media queries on resize @setek

Comment: @srekoble I used <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0,minumum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: If you are testing by resizing browser window, just change your media queries from `max-device-width` to `max-width` and `min-device-width` to `min-width`. `min-width`, `max-width` target browser dimensions. `max-device-width`, `min-device-width` target device dimensions irrespective of browser size.

Comment: @srvikram13 got it, now I understand where my logic was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Your rule says `max-device-width` not `max-width`, which means, as long as your monitor is wider than `480px`, you're not going to see anything different. Either check on a small screen or update it to `max-width` for Responsive Design rather than Adaptive."

You can use Chrome to pretend change the "device width" by pulling up the Inspector (right-click and Inspect Element) then click on "Show Console" button in top right (looks like a > with three horizontal lines next to it) click on Emulation tab, and then choose a Device to emulate (pick iPhone 4, it has a max-width of 320 [well, 640 but with a font-scale factor of 2, which is 320.]) Then hit Emulate and it will update the "device width".

I.E.:

Your `max-device-width` is the width of your **monitor**, not browser window. So, mine is  1920px. It won't change unless I change my monitor's resolution.

Your `max-width` is the width of your browser window. That, unlike the above, **does** change on resize.

Comment: I understand where my logic was off, and I completely overlooked that! Thank you very much for explaining that to me!